# GridView SelectedIndexChanged Event is not fired

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want my GridView Rows to fire the SelectedIndexChanged event when I click on them.

I tried the following in code behind:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "Highlight(this)");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "UnHighlight(this)");

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select${0}')", e.Row.RowIndex));
        }
    }
```

Postback happens when I click on a row, but it doesn't fires SelectedIndexChanged. In the Page_Load I get the arguments from the request:

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            object obTarget = this.Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]; //GridView1
            object obArg = this.Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; //Select$4
        }
```

I think that SelectedIndexChanged would have to be raised, or do i have a misunderstanding on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably rebinding the GridView to its DataSource on postback. You should do that only `if(!IsPostBack)` (with enabled ViewState), otherwise events aren't triggered.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DatSource = GetGataSource();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

You should also register event handler on every postback but `RowDataBound` is only called on databinding. So use [`RowCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) instead.

It's also better to use [`Page.GetPostBackClientHyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getpostbackclienthyperlink.aspx) instead of hardcoding the javascript function.

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink((GridView)sender, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Comment: Replacing the hard coded javascript has solved the problem, thanks a lot. The difference was, that the __EVENTTARGET got the value of "ctl00$MainContent$GridView1" instead of just "GridView1" as it was with the hardcoded version